# How to sort nsmutablearray with two key values

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray, nssortdescriptor

My `NSMutableArray` Values as follows

I want to sort this array alphabetically using "`category_name`" and `total_assets` > `0.00`

Suggest me some sorting code

```
{
    CID = 1;
    "category_name" = Art;
    "rbg_color" = "1,187,212";
    "total_assets" = "12500.00";
},
{
    CID = 2;
    "category_name" = Automobile;
    "rbg_color" = "244,66,54";
    "total_assets" = "102600.00";
},
{
    CID = 3;
    "category_name" = Banks;
    "rbg_color" = "1,149,135";
    "total_assets" = "0.00";
},
{
    CID = 4;
    "category_name" = Cash;
    "rbg_color" = "75,175,79";
    "total_assets" = "25000.00";
},
{
    CID = 5;
    "category_name" = Clothing;
    "rbg_color" = "103,57,182";
    "total_assets" = "0.00";
},
{
    CID = 7;
    "category_name" = Electronics;
    "rbg_color" = "32,149,242";
    "total_assets" = "0.00";
},

{
    CID = 10;
    "category_name" = Watches;
    "rbg_color" = "139,194,74";
    "total_assets" = "0.00";
},
{
    CID = 11;
    "category_name" = Wine;
    "rbg_color" = "62,80,180";
    "total_assets" = "30500.00";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your friends are [NSPredicat](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/) and [NSSortDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/) you can find Apple documentation for the both in the links provided , an easy way to do that is the following :

```
-(void)sortMeyhod
{
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
   //here you initialize the descriptor with key category_name , and it is case insensitive i.e capital or small
   sortDescriptor=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"category_name"
                                           ascending:YES
                                           selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
   //create your descriptors array .
   sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
   //sort your array . 
   yourArray  = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    //filter your array with a predicate . 
   NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K > 0.00" , @"total_assets"] ;
   yourArray =[yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] ; 
}
```

i did not fully test the code but theoretically it should work , and also please refer to the documentation .

Comment: what would be the `messages` here ?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor  = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"category_name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K > 0.00" , @"total_assets"] ;
sortedArray = [sortedArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

NSLog(@"%@",sortedArray);
```

Comment: Crashed with error  : [__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector

Comment: i fixed using `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K > %@" , @"total_assets",@"0.00"] ;`

Comment: I tried it in Xcode 7 beta 5.0 it worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"category_name" ascending:YES];
tempArray=[yourArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];

NSSortDescriptor *sort1 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"total_assets" ascending:YES];
sortedArray=[tempArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort1]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally its solved:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor  = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"category_name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedCatg = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K > %@" , @"total_assets",@"0.00"] ;
sortedCatg = [sortedCatg filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %@" , @"total_assets",@"0.00"] ;
NSArray *sortedAssets = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate1];

myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[myArray addObjectsFromArray:sortedCatg];
[myArray addObjectsFromArray:sortedAssets];
```